# Twitter Bootstrap not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, webview

HTML file(test.html) is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    Learn more
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML and bootstrap css files are placed in assets folder. If I open the HTML file in IE/Firefox, it is displayed correctly. But Android WebView does not render this properly

Code for WebView is

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String url = "file:///android_asset/test.html";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

IE renders it like this

[image: IE Renders it like this]

WebView renders it like this

[image: WebView Renders it like this]

What is wrong?

Comment: have you hooked your device up to your pc to see if the css files are loading (ie not 404'ing).

Comment: i have set up a test project with your code an am unable to reproduce this problem, neither on emulator nor device. Can you elaborate on your environment, android level, bootstrap version, etc. ?

Comment: the css could be (although unlikely) using imports from external sources - if ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` wasn't set in the Manifest that could be your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, no storage is being accessed. setJavaScriptEnabled(true) is also unnecessary for this particular example, although it's not the problem and I'm sure it's planned to be used later.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on emulator - Android version 4.2 with Bootstrap v2.3.2

Files in my app's assets folder:

```
 bootstrap-responsive.css
 bootstrap.css
 test.html
```

No need to add "android.permission.INTERNET" in Android manifest since css files are available locally within the app's asset folder.

Here's a screenshot of how it is rendered. There is no reason why you could not see it unless there are issues with the CSS files (which is again unlikely since you can see the results on browser).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
  String htmlData ="<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\">"+yourdata;    
  webview.loadData(htmlData, "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin:

```
webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```